# Relocating files related to .Net MVC3 Unobtrusive AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

A simple question (I hope):

We have a set structure within our projects for Assets, that being /Assets/img/, /Assets/css/ and /Assets/js/

I've been reading Brad Wilson's [excellent article on Unobtrusive AJAX](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html), in which he mentions the files required, FTA:

> In addition to setting the flag, you will also need to include two script files: jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js) and the MVC plugin for unobtrusive Ajax with jQuery (~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js).

Is anyone aware of a way of informing MVC to look in a folder other than /Scripts/ for these files - I don't want to add a whole folder in the root of the project just for these 2 files.

**UPDATE**
Oh dear, end of the day brain-rot obviously. Sorry all!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, you can use whatever path you want to set up for your scripts:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have mine pointed to the Scripts folder as that is what was set up by default, but you can change that to your specific path.

Comment: I was having a stupid moment, sorry. Just to add some value back to the conversation - I recommend using UrlHelper Extension methods. So instead you can do <script src="@Url.JavaScript("jquery.etc.js")" type="text/javascript">

Comment: @beardtwizzle as far as I know, Url.JavaScript is not a standard extension. So I assume that someone on your team added that extension method an told it to point at your 'Assets/js' folder?

Comment: @NerdFury - yes they [me] did. It allows us to easily change file location by updating 1 reference - should we ever need to.

Answer (score 0):

the way that I have seen it done is to create an extension method on the `HtmlHelper` class for including javascript.

```
public static string Script(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename)
{
  if(!filename.EndsWith(".js")) filename += ".js";
  var path = string.Format("<script src='/Assets/js/{0}' type="text/javascript"></script>", filename);
  return path;
}
```

then in your master page you can add this block to the header

```
<%= Html.Script("jquery-1.4.1") %>
<%= Html.Script("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min") %>
```

Comment: or use the equivalent razor syntax, since you are using mvc 3, and probably using razor. But I don't know for sure. And I haven't done enough with razor to add it. This method comes from Rob Conery's Tekpub series on MVC2 btw.